# Retention Policy Not Applied to Database (and not working)

Tags: influxdb

I am running out of disk space, and I am not sure why the retention policy that I had created, wasn't "used". I created a new retention policy, but it also doesn't seem to be used.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the `influx settings` command in your docker won't show you the immediate change. Could you double check your docker session?

Another way to confirm a list of retention policies for the specified database is to run following query:

```
SHOW RETENTION POLICIES ON patience
```

And you should be able to see your rp '30_day' listed in the result and it is the default one now.